# Merge given list and dictionary into json structure

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

From comments: 
I am trying to achive the json data structure for implementing graph which input is in json , and above input and output list maps to the key.

Input:

```
key =['c','d']
in = {'input':['a','b']}
out ={'output':['b','d']}
```

Output:

```
{'c':{'input':'a','output:'b'},
 'd':{'input':'b','output:'d'}
```

Used defaultdict but the dictionary data confines to the last value.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you are trying to achieve (in addition to the title) & what does your code look like so far?

Comment: Trying to achive the json data structure for implementing graph  which input is in json  , and above input and output list maps to the key.

Comment: Your output isn't valid JSON. What attempts have you made generating that output?

Comment: Thanks for the comments , I derailed this way and got the required output  without creating unnecessary list key and dicts , in and out .